# get column name and value from multivalue field in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have field like this

```
D1=1.05,D2=1.05,D3=0.84,L1=1.12,L2=1.12,L3=1.12,L12=0.6,L22=0.6,L32=0.4800,I1=0.5,I2=0.5,I3=0.38,A=90,OF=-1
```

how could i make that look like this

```
D1   D2    D3   L1   L2  L3   L12 L22 L32  I1  I2   I3  A  OF
1.05 1.05 0.84 1.12 1.12 1.12 0.6 0.6 0.48 0.5 0.5 0.38 90 -1
```

Comment: Split it in your application code and insert into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a value, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)='D1=1.05,D2=1.05,D3=0.84,L1=1.12,L2=1.12,L3=1.12,L12=0.6,L22=0.6,L32=0.4800,I1=0.5,I2=0.5,I3=0.38,A=90,OF=-1'
SET @s='select ['+REPLACE(REPLACE(@s,'=',']='),',',',[')
PRINT @s
EXEC(@s)
```

```
D1  D2  D3  L1  L2  L3  L12 L22 L32 I1  I2  I3  A   OF
1.05    1.05    0.84    1.12    1.12    1.12    0.6 0.6 0.4800  0.5 0.5 0.38    90  -1
```

**Using split string and PIVOT**

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(col varchar(max))
INSERT INTO #tt(col)VALUES('D1=1.05,D2=1.05,D3=0.84,L1=1.12,L2=1.12,L3=1.12,L12=0.6,L22=0.6,L32=0.4800,I1=0.5,I2=0.5,I3=0.38,A=90,OF=-1')

DECLARE @col VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(max)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
SELECT y.* INTO #t FROM #tt AS t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CONVERT(XML,'<n><t>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(t.col,'=','</t><v>'),',','</v></n><n><t>')+'</v></n>'))) x(xcol)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT x.n.value('t[1]','varchar(200)') AS title, x.n.value('v[1]','varchar(200)') AS val FROM x.xcol.nodes('n') x(n)) y

SELECT @col=ISNULL(@col+',','')+QUOTENAME(title) FROM #t GROUP BY title
SET @sql='select * from #t pivot(max(val) for title in ('+@col+')) p'
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

**Process multiple rows:**
As the following sample data, There are two new column (B and D4) in line 2.

The columns list of result is combining all of columns for all the data line.
Is it matched your requirment?

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(ID INT,col varchar(max))
INSERT INTO #tt(ID,col)VALUES(1,'D1=1.05,D2=1.05,D3=0.84,L1=1.12,L2=1.12,L3=1.12,L12=0.6,L22=0.6,L32=0.4800,I1=0.5,I2=0.5,I3=0.38,A=90,OF=-1')
                            ,(2,'D1=1.06,D2=1.06,D3=0.84,D4=1.84,L1=1.12,L2=1.12,L3=2.12,L12=0.6,L22=0.6,L32=0.5800,I1=0.5,I2=0.5,I3=1.38,A=90,B=99,OF=-1')


DECLARE @col VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(max)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
SELECT ID, y.* INTO #t FROM #tt AS t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CONVERT(XML,'<n><t>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(t.col,'=','</t><v>'),',','</v></n><n><t>')+'</v></n>'))) x(xcol)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT x.n.value('t[1]','varchar(200)') AS title, x.n.value('v[1]','varchar(200)') AS val FROM x.xcol.nodes('n') x(n)) y

SELECT @col=ISNULL(@col+',','')+QUOTENAME(title) FROM #t GROUP BY title
SET @sql='select * from #t pivot(max(val) for title in ('+@col+')) p'
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

```
ID  A   B   D1  D2  D3  D4  I1  I2  I3  L1  L12 L2  L22 L3  L32 OF
1   90  NULL    1.05    1.05    0.84    NULL    0.5 0.5 0.38    1.12    0.6 1.12    0.6 1.12    0.4800  -1
2   90  99  1.06    1.06    0.84    1.84    0.5 0.5 1.38    1.12    0.6 1.12    0.6 2.12    0.5800  -1
```

Comment: Tnx for your reply but i have a column in table that it's value is like i posted in my question how can i split that column value?

Comment: @mohammadabbasi  the statement in my answer as "Using split string and PIVOT" is split a value from a column. It just demonstrated one line, Is it possible exist other data that has different values pair with your had pasted?

Comment: yes . but i want to create a stored procedure to filter table(based on filter that column has one pair value format)

Comment: @mohammadabbasi I created a new sample in my answer, I am not sure, whether it is matched with your scenario